# Can Maaco do exact/close to exact colors from auto dealers?

Tags: paint, body-work

I’m looking to get a paint job from Maaco, and I really like the “destroyer grey” dodge offers from 2017-2020, can Maaco match this paint code without being thousands of dollars? They quoted me at $675 for a matte black job

Comment: There are actually two questions here: a) Can Maaco match the color? and b) Can they do it "without being thousands of dollars?" The first is a good question, but the second veers into a price/shopping question, which is off-topic here. I suggest you amend your title and question (using the "edit" link below the question text) to focus on only the first issue.

Comment: Matching the color does not mean it has the same resin as the manufacturers paint. Dealers often need an electronic analyser to match their own colors for a repaint.

Comment: $675 is not thousands of dollars.

Comment: I would call up Maaco on the phone and ask?

Comment: I last painted a car in 1990 ,paint alone for a smallish car ( 300 ZX) cost about $300 . So don't expect much for $ 675 today.